# Not centering with \[ \]

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

I was using a template for a book in overleaf:
[Book Template](https://www.overleaf.com/articles/clustering-the-interstellar-medium/mtthgyyfrdkn#.WV1FpYjysaY)

Every time I try to use `\[ \]` the equation is not centered. It is added onto a new line, but not centered. In order to center it I have to use `$$ $$`, I would prefer not to as I have used the former for all my previous papers and I keep on having to rewrite it. I can't seem to find what part of the header edited the typical behavior of `\[ \]` or if it's something with regards to the documentclass (I have only used article up to now, it is my first time using the book class). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Didn't load the document class, or `amsmath` with option `[fleqn]`? Or doesn't some package load this option?

Comment: the first line of the file is `\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book} % Default font size and left-justified equations`   which documents the fleqn option and that equations are flush left